# Entity Framework ignores Table Annotation

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have some existing tables in the database (Order, Customer) that I can't change, and I am creating new tables as part of the project that I would prefer to pluralize (eg., Coupons). I am using EF 6.1 with Code First.

For some reason, when EF generates internal SQL, it ignores [Table()] annotation. In other words, if I ask EF to pluralize the names, *all* SQL statements have `SELECT ... FROM Orders`. If I remove the pluralization (`modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();`) then I get `SELECT ... FROM Coupon`. I **have** `[Table("Order")]` and `[Table("Coupons")]` but it doesn't seem to make any effect!

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for here:

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<PocoName>().ToTable("SomeOtherString") ;
```

Comment: I'll try (for now I renamed the new table; Coupon instead of Coupons). But are you saying that [Table()] is *indeed*. Is it by design or a bug in EF? There are numerous posts about EF (mostly older; EF4 or 5) - and many of the mention Table attribute as one of the ways to affect generated SQL...

Comment: I dont think it is ignored. I think when you mix and match annotations and Fluent API, fluent wins.   sorry i dont have the have test handy to confirm the various scenarios

Comment: ok, thanks, I'll play around... I didn't have fluent APIs; and I didn't see effect of annotations.